# How to create an excel file with sas variables

Tags: sas

SAS code:

To create an excel file for the youngest child that contains (first name, DOB and name).

last name   first name  DOB of Child    Name of Child

Brian           Geogg           20-Nov-97        Ginger
Serrano         Amelia          21-Nov-00        Garlic
Sinha           Ravi            17-Oct-90        Onion
Nagasaka    Kanoko          7-Aug-96         Bats

Any input would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SAS/ACCESS to PC FILES licensed, PROC EXPORT can handle it for you:

```
proc export data=<yourdata> outfile=<yourexcelfile.xls> dbms=excel replace;
run;
```

IF you do not, then ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP is probably your best bet.

```
ods tagsets.excelxp file=<yourexcelfile.xls>;
proc print data=<mydata>;
run;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

There are all sorts of options you'd want to use if you do it that way, google about for more information.

Comment: Thanks man very useful input - would you happen to know how to create an excel file from dataset output using libname.

Comment: Why do you want to use libname?

Comment: I used libname to import the excel file into sas and wanted to keep it consistent and try and figure out how to use libname to create the excel file with the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: Libname statement for export is the same as for import.  Define the libname, then treat it as if it were a SAS library.